# Layout of PHP form needs altering

Tags: php, html, forms, layout

Part of code:

```
echo "<form method ='post' action='NextFile.cgi'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Date: </td></td>  <input type='date' name='Date' value =".$record['Date']." autofocus required='required'
                                    /></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Time: </td></td>  <input type='time' name='Time' value=".$record['Time']." autofocus required='required'
                                    /></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submitname' value='Save' />";
echo "</form>";
```

`$record` is related to the mysql query.

When running the code in a web browser, the two input boxes are displayed side by side.

Below are the characters `/>`
Below is 'Date:'
Below is 'Time:'

I am trying to alter the code so that `Date:` is beside the Date input box, and the same for Time below.

How can I do it?

Comment: Aside from you doing this in php, does it have anything to do with php? or is this a pure html question at its heart?

Comment: You have two consecutive closing `</td>`. change one in an opening `<td>` and you'll have two columns.

Comment: @MichaelIT it isn't actually, thought I thought so at first.  It's a PHP syntax error with the text strings

Comment: Also please look into php heredoc https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is your `</td></td>` which should be `</td><td>`

```
$date = $record["Date"];
$time = $record["Time"];
<form method ="post" action="NextFile.cgi">
<table>
<tr><td>Date: </td><td><input type="date" name="Date"$date" autofocus required="required"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Time: </td><td><input type="time" name="Time"$time" autofocus required="required"/></td></tr>
</table>"
<input type="submit" name="submitname" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up version of your code:

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>Date: </td> <input type="date" name="Date" "value="'.$record['Date'].'" autofocus required="required" /></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Time: </td>  <input type="time" name="Time" value="'.$record['Time'].'" autofocus required="required"/></td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

As an explanation, I added the quotes  around your values (not sure if that was causing your issue, but it's good form; and your results might have erred without it) and removed the second close row `</td>` as was mentioned above.

Edit:  try it now

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I receive the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$record['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' on line 75`

Comment: Downvote because the code didn't work and didn't fix horrible echo's

Comment: okay it is fixed now.  I generally don't like encapsulating inside double quotes;  I find this easier to parse